# Is there a way to alpha mask a composable?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to apply an alpha mask/blend (Porter-Duff destination-in composition) to a composable, from another composable, not just clip it.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I need to do the same thing and haven't had success so far.

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for a way of doing something similar to achieve a fading edge effect in a scrollable `Row`. I ended up finding [this medium article](https://medium.com/@helmersebastian/fading-edges-modifier-in-jetpack-compose-af94159fdf1f) which implements the fading edges for a `Column`/`verticalScroll` and I was able to come up with some code for `Row`/`horizontalScroll` too.

Coming back to your question, I'm not 100% sure this solution applies to your case since I don't know what you mean by *"apply an alpha mask/blend [...] from another composable"* but you can draw a mask shape on top of the `Composable` and use `BlendMode.DstOut` or `BlendMode.DstIn` to only display parts of the original `Composable` based on that drawn mask, using `drawWithContent`.

You also need to use `.graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.99F }` modifier before `drawWithContent` so it works properly with blend modes.

For example, let's say you have a `Text` composable and you want to add some transparency to the bottom of it, so it fades out towards the bottom, you can do it like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FadingText() {
    Text(
        text = """
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Nullam euismod, nisl eget aliquam ultricies, 
            quam sapien aliquet nunc, quis ultricies nisl nunc quis nunc. 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Nullam euismod, nisl eget aliquam ultricies,
            quam sapien aliquet nunc, quis ultricies nisl nunc quis nunc.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Nullam euismod, nisl eget aliquam ultricies,
            quam sapien aliquet nunc, quis ultricies nisl nunc quis nunc.
        """.trimIndent(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.99f }
            .drawWithContent {
                // draw content first
                drawContent()

                // draw a rectangle which will act as a mask
                // since we are using BlendMode.DstIn, the content alpha will basically be
                // the same as the rectangle alpha at any point. You can use any color here since
                // DstIn will only use the alpha channel of the color.
                drawRect(
                    brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(Color.Black, Color.Transparent),
                        startY = size.height - 120.dp.toPx(),
                        endY = size.height
                    ),
                    blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn,
                )
            }
    )
}
```

Here's a preview of what that looks like:
[image: FadingText Preview]

For those interested in the `horizontalScroll` and `verticalScroll` fading edges modifiers, here's my GitHub Gist:
https://gist.github.com/thomashorta/eaee1b2f2111d80f087373b60593e16f

Answer (score 0):

There's an `alpha(Float)` modifier. If the composable accepts the `modifier` parameter, we can just append `Modifier.alpha(value)` to it.

All standard composables accept the `modifier` parameter. It's generally useful to add the modifier parameter to our composables.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(modifier: Modifier, alpha: Float) {
    // Any base composable which accepts a modifier
    Column(modifier = modifier.alpha(alpha)) {
        // content...
    }
}
```

---

```
MyComposable(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), alpha = 0.5f)
```

---

However, if it's not possible then we can always wrap the composable within a `Box` and apply the `alpha` modifier to it. There can be a wrapper composable (let's say `AlphaMask()`) which does this.

```
/**
 * @param alpha: Alpha value between 0f..1f
 */
@Composable
fun AlphaMask(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, alpha: Float = 1f, content: @Composable () -> Unit){
    Box(modifier.alpha(alpha)){
        content()
    }
}
```

---

```
@Composable
fun Usage(){
    AlphaMask(alpha = 0.5f) {
        AnyGeneralComposable()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don´t need to apply an uniform alpha to the whole composable, what I need is a composition using another composable as a mask, eventually using the mask-composable alpha (Porter-Duff dst in)